# Difference between javascript.prototype.abc and javascript.prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am wondering about javascript prototype. I know that prototyping enables the user to add new  properties and methods to a constructor or an object.

I have used the following several times:

```
function Example() {}
Example.prototype.add = function () {};
Example.prototype.sub = someVar;
```

This way I can use Example.add as a function and Example.sub as an element of object.
But happens when someone writes something like this

```
Example.prototype = function() {
                    //Code
                    };
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at a simple example:

```
 var Person = function(args){
     this.init(args);
 }
```

When defining a few methods for the person prototype we would do this:

```
 Person.prototype = {
     getAge : function(){},
     nickname : "R2D2"
 };
```

Or

```
 Person.prototype.getAge = function() {...};
 Person.prototype.nickName= "R2D2";
```

Both do the same thing. I prefer the first version because it's easier to read and needs less characters to write ( making the footprint of my code smaller ).

The only reason I could think of for using

```
 Person.prototype = function(){}
```

is to create a private scope available only to the prototype of the Person. But this requires a self executing function which returns an object.

```
 Person.prototype = (function(){
    var theAnswerToEverything = 42;
    return {
        getTheAnswerToEverything : function(){
           return theAnswerToEverything;
        }
    };
 })();
```

theAnswerToEverything will be a variable usable only by the methods of the Persons prototype. More complex examples could be created by using the same principle.

Comment: I understand your proposition of using a self executing function to create a local scope, however in your example the prototype is not a function.

Comment: I know. That's the closest thing that I could think of for using the word function, near the word prototype. :) Like you said, the prototype is an OBJECT... I wonder what happens if you set the prototype of an object to a function, which has an object prototype.

Answer (score 3):

The prototype is the place where javascript looks for methods/variables.

When using new the prototype of the constructor is also given to the the created object.

As a consequence, prototype must be an **OBJECT** (and you can change its content).

The main usage of the prototype is to have :

```
var myExample = new Example();
myExample.add() => call the add function of the prototype with this = myExample.
```

EDIT : Because functions are objects, assigning a function to the prototype should work (you can still add properties to it which can be functions). However, I do not see any useful usecase for doing that

Comment: Since I can define Example.prototype.add = function(); and Example.prototype.sub = Var; So does it mean the prototype is acting like a container where objects are present?

And Example.prototype = function() {} can be only one object or function at a time?

Answer (score 1):

*Example.prototype* should refer to an OBJECT - not a function.  In your first example:

```
Example.prototype.add = function () {}; 
Example.prototype.sub = someVar;
```

You correctly adding properties to the prototype (remember, an object).  So the 2 properties you've added will automatically appear on objects created by *new Example*().

```
Example.prototype = function() {};
```

You have replaced the prototype with another object, namely an object that so happen is a function (remember a Javascript function is still an object).  It is the properties of this function that get inherited by the object created by the *new Example*() expression.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript functions are also objects.

So in your case, prototype becomes a member of Example object.

if you had

```
Example.prototype = function() { alert('hi'); };
```

then calling

```
Example.prototype()
```

would alert "hi"

Comment: In javascript everything goes :) , you can do ' var undefined = true; ' and feel the magic.(There are safeguards, ofcourse)

Answer (score 0):

You just override the prototype with the function object. It will not be invoked when looking up attributes on objects created using `new Example`, but it will work as any other prototype object, and you can give it attributes like

```
Example.prototype.foo = 8;
console.log(new Example().foo); // 8
```